# Javascript: Get scoped variable

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I'm writing a counter to count an object, and it looks like this:

```
function myFunc(param) {
  this.param = param;

  param.foo = function() {
    var object = window.JSON.parse(data);
    for (i in object) {
      counter++;
    }
  }

}

var foo = new myFunc('data.json');
var counter = 0;
document.write(counter); // displays 0
```

How can I achieve to get the counter value outside the function? I tried almost everything, from `window` to `return` to separate `functions`.

Any clue?

**Update**

I prefer a better design like this

```
function myFunc(param) {
  this.param = param;

  param.foo = function() {
    var object = window.JSON.parse(data);
    var counter = 0;
    for (i in object) {
      counter++;
    }
    return counter;
  }

}

var foo = new myFunc('data.json');
document.write(counter); // displays undefined
```

**Update 2**

Sorry, thought it would be easier to have a sample code. But here's the real one: https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/e709ec303477a015b609

Comment: That's a bad design. Instances shouldn't modify global(or outer) variables. If you just want to create one instance of that constructor then there is no need to define a constructor, Use a singleton.

Comment: What is a "data" in "window.JSON.parse(data)" ?

Comment: @Vohuman Updated the code, this gives me ``undefined``

Comment: `data = this.param`?

Comment: @Art713 It's a JSON file the counter is looping through. I think it's out of content for the particular problem, but can post the real code if necessary

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a couple issues here.

First, you're setting your `counter` to `0` just before you write. It will always be `0` no matter what you do, even with hoisting.

Second, you never call the `foo` function, so your `counter` is never incremented.

Third, `param.foo` isn't public. I think you want it to be `this.foo = function(){ ... }`.

Here's a simplified version of the code you posted with my tweaks:

```
var counter = 0;
var foo;

function myFunc() {
  this.foo = function() {
    counter = 1000;
  }
}

foo = new myFunc();
foo.foo();
document.write(counter);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/2ojw2332/2/
Note that JSFiddle doesn't allow `document.write`, so replaced that part.

Comment: Weird thing going on. Writing or console logging still shows ``0``. But when I type ``counter`` in the chrome dev tools command line it displays ``173``, the correct number.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunc(param) {
    this.param = param;
    this.foo = function () {
        var object = window.JSON.parse(this.param),
            counter = 0,
            i;
        for (i in object) {
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    };
}
var foo = new myFunc('{"a":99}');
out(foo.foo());

function out(s) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = '<pre>' + s + '</pre>';
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it's what I'm trying to do now. I updated my question with the original function, the one I'm really using.

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing this now ``out(data.xobj.onload());
function out(s) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = '<pre>' + s + '</pre>';
}``, but gives me ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onload' of undefined``. Am I doing something wrong? Or should I wrap ``xobj.onload`` in another function?

Comment: the data you retrieve is asynchron. the problem with that is, you process the data and the data is not received.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nina Scholz pointed out earlier, I'm retrieving the data asynchron. Javascript started painting the dom before all the values where loaded.

This fixed my problem:

```
if (document.readyState) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var objLen = Object.keys(obj).length;
    console.log(objLen);
  }, 100);
}
```

I'm waiting for the document to be ready, then add an additional timeout as buffer.